# JQUERY Manipulate xml data

Tags: jquery, xml

I have the following XML

```
<response>
    <item>
        <sku>83340</sku>
        <vendor>83340</vendor>
        <errors>
            <msg>Real-Time Error</msg>
        </errors>
    </item>
    <item>
        <sku>83340</sku>
    </item>
    <item>
        <sku>05319GS11007</sku>
         <vendor>83340</vendor>
        <errors>
            <msg>Fatal Error</msg>
        </errors>
    </item>
</response>
```

Using JQUERY, I want to search for the items with ERRORs only and get the corresponding SKU.

I can find the item with errors but how can i get the corresponding SKU so that I can say that the SKU has an error:

```
var errors = '';
jQuery(res).find("errors").each(function ( i ) {
            jQuery(this).find("msg").each(function () {
                errors += ' - ' + jQuery(this).text(); + '\n'
            });
        });
```

something like this

```
jQuery(res).find("item").each(function ( i ) {
            if(jQuery(this).has( "error" )){
                var stSKU = jQuery(this).find("sku").text();
                var stError = jQuery(this).find("msg").text();.each(function () {
                    errors += ' # SKU # 'stSKU ' - ' + stError + '\n'
                });
            }
        });
```

Output will be like:

```
 SKU # 83340 has Real Time Error. 
 SKU # 05319GS11007 has  Fatal Error.
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `jQuery.parseXML()` to parse any `XML`.

For more read [here](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/)

```js
var xml = `<response>
    <item>
        <sku>83340</sku>
        <vendor>83340</vendor>
        <errors>
            <msg>Real-Time Error</msg>
        </errors>
    </item>
    <item>
        <sku>83340</sku>
    </item>
    <item>
        <sku>05319GS11007</sku>
         <vendor>83340</vendor>
        <errors>
            <msg>Fatal Error</msg>
        </errors>
    </item>
</response>`;

var xmlObj = $.parseXML( xml );
var err;
$(xmlObj).find("item").each(function(item){
   err = $(this).find("errors");
   if(err.length){
     console.log("SKU #" + $(this).find("sku").text() + " has " + $(err).find("msg").text());
     }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```